# IE7 and the CSS table-cell property

Tags: css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7, css-tables

So I just love it when my application is working great in Firefox, but then I open it in IE and... Nope, please try again.

The issue I'm having is that I'm setting a CSS display property to either `none` or `table-cell` with JavaScript.

I was initially using `display: block`, but Firefox was rendering it weird without the `table-cell` property.

I would love to do this without adding a hack in the JavaScript to test for IE.  Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Amusing, you use a hack for firefox then look for an IE hack..;)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A good way of solving this setting the `display` value to `''`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function toggle( elemntId ) {
    if (document.getElementById( elemntId ).style.display != 'none') {
        document.getElementById( elemntId ).style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        document.getElementById( elemntId ).style.display = '';
    }
    return true;
}
//-->
</script>
```

The empty value causes the style to revert back to it's default value. This solution works across all major browsers.

Comment: In chrome, you can set it to `initial`. :)

Comment: the `initial` keyword is being added in CSS3 and does behave exactly as the above does, according to the specifications.

Comment: I love these kind of hacks :)

Answer (score 48):

I've solved this using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 7)
  {
    $(".tablecell").wrap("<td />");
    $(".tablerow").wrap("<tr />");
    $(".table").wrapInner("<table />");
  }
});
```

the above script assumes you have divs using style such as:

```
<style>
.table     { display: table; }
.tablerow  { display: table-row; }
.tablecell { display: table-cell; }
</style>
```

Comment: @andy magoon, Is there's a solution like this without the .browser property, now that's deprecated by jQuery? Or just creating our own browser detecting code is the only solution?

Comment: @raphie Make a separated .js and use conditional comments =/

Comment: @RaphaelDDL thank you for the suggestion, yes I had to create my own browser detection code at least to detect basic type of systems like iOS, Android or Windows, and some main browsers like Gecko/Mozilla, webkit, safari and ie.

Comment: I also had to wrap the whole thing into <tbody /> to get IE7 to render the table

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue and used

```
*float: left;
```

"*" indicates IE only

Comment: To be precise, the `*` (asterisk) hack addresses IE 7 and below.

Comment: The * is a nice trick, but float won't give you evenly spaced elements, which is what you want in a table.

Answer (score 4):

Well, [IE7 does not have `display: table(-cell/-row)`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html) so you will have to figure something else out or do browser targeting (which I agree, is bad hack). As a quick fix (I don't know what you're trying to achieve, appearance-wise) you could try `display: inline-block` and see what it looks like.

Maybe figure out a way to do `display: block` and solve the problem of "Firefox rendering it weird" instead? Can you describe what you mean by the weird rendering exactly?

Comment: When you set it to block in Firefox, it renders the table cells on top of each other instead of side by side.

I would rewrite the whole thing to use DIVs instead, but I'm far to lazy for that, so I just wrote the sh**ty hack code instead.

Comment: If you are doing block-level elements of some kind, you could set them to float "float: left" so in Firefox they will stack up next to each other instead of in rows. Or "display: inline-block" might work here, but in IE7 it can only be used on elements that would normally be inline, like a or em.

Comment: IE7 doesn't support <code>display:inline-block;</code>. An apparent hack is <code>zoom: 1; *display: inline;</code>

Answer (score 4):

You never need Javascript to test for IE, use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

You might look at the solution [these guys](http://www.tjkdesign.com/articles/css-layout/no_div_no_float_no_clear_no_hack_no_joke.asp) came up with for handling table-like display in IE.

Answer (score 4):

Using inline-block works well for this type of stuff. No, IE 6 and IE 7 technically do not have display: inline-block, but you can replicate the behavior with the following styles:

```
div.show-ib {
    display: inline-block;
    *zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
}
```

The key to this is 'zoom: 1' toggles the 'hasLayout' property on the element which changes the way the browser renders a block level element. The only gotcha with inline block is you cannot have a margin of less than 4px.

Comment: +100 Very good answer. Works way better than any other solution I've come across!

Answer (score 3):

I've been using CSS for over a decade and I've never had occasion to use display:table-cell, and the only times I ever use conditional comments are to hide advanced effects from IE6.

I suspect that a different approach would solve your problem in an intrinsically cross-browser way. Can you open a separate question that describes the effect you're trying to achieve, and post the HTML and CSS that's currently working in Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

A code example fot the conditional comments that user eyelidlessness, kindly posted

"[if lt IE 8]" only works if the browser is IE lower than IE8 because IE8 does it right. With the conditional comments IE7 arranges the DIVs nicely horizontally...
HTML:

```
 <div class="container">
    <!--[if lt IE 8 ]><table><tr><![endif]--> 
    <!--[if lt IE 8 ]><td><![endif]-->
    <div class="link"><a href="en.html">English</a></div>
    <!--[if lt IE 8 ]></td><![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 8 ]><td><![endif]-->
    <div tabindex="0" class="thumb"><img src="pictures\pic.jpg" /></div>
    <!--[if lt IE 8 ]></td><![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 8 ]><td><![endif]-->
    <div class="link"><a href="de.html">Deutsch</a></div>
    <!--[if lt IE 8 ]></td><![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 8 ]></tr></table><![endif]-->
</div>
```

My CSS

```
.link {
 display:table-cell;
 vertical-align:middle;
 }
 div.container {
 margin: 0 auto;
 display:table;
 }
 .thumb {
 display:table-cell;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
 }
```

IE 8 and 9 Work with the CSS as does FireFox. IE7 looks now the same using the Table and TD & TR tags. On some pages IE 8 worked only 20% of the time, so I used [if lt IE 9 ]

This also helps smoothing out vertical-align issues that IE7 can't handle.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything and the only way I found that was all cross browser was to use Javascript / Jquery. This is a clean lightweight solution:  [click here](http://www.ddrewdesign.com/blog/jquery-vertical-align-function)

Answer (score 0):

IE7 doesn't support `display:inline-block;` either. An apparent hack is `zoom: 1; *display: inline;` after your css for `display:table-cell;`