# display: table dosen't work in ie6 & ie7

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

i create a menu but it doesn't work in ie6 & ie7 because of `display:table`. how can i do this to work in ie6 and ie7 with style `display:table`

there is my example

http://jsfiddle.net/amkrtchyan/fCsax/

but it doesn't work in ie6 and ie7

Comment: I came across this article: http://tanalin.com/en/projects/display-table-htc/

Comment: i try it but it doesn't work :)

Comment: What exactly does not work for you? Have you read its webpage carefully?

Answer (score 8):

IE6 and IE7 do not support display: table;

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

You can either use a real table if its tabular data, otherwise you can use lists (ul) and inline-block with the *display:inline hack and zoom:1 for IE7 and below.

Comment: but need to work with `display:table`

Comment: @AramMkrtchyan: IE 6 and IE 7 don’t support `display:table`. It really is that simple.

Comment: i know it... i can try alternative css for ie6 and ie7 ,but where I work so need to work with display : table

Answer (score 1):

IE7 doesn't support display:table, so you have to rebuild the menu in a different way or you can use js for this

check this [IE7 and the CSS table-cell property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249103/ie7-and-the-css-table-cell-property)

Answer (score 1):

I see that you’re using `display:table` to achieve a side-by-side layout of the menu items.

I think you can produce a similar result in IE 6 and 7 using `display:inline-block` on the menu items:

- http://jsfiddle.net/fCsax/3/

The differences between your original and this version are:

1. Remove `display:table` from `.menu`
2. Add `overflow: hidden` to `.menu` so that its rounded corners clip its menu items too
3. Remove `display:table-row` from `.menu ul`
4. Add `display:inline` to `.menu li`
5. Move the padding from `.menu li` to `.menu ul li a`
6. Add `display:inline-block` to `.menu ul li a`

I’ve had a quick look in IE 6, and I think it’s working:

- http://jsfiddle.net/fCsax/3/embedded/result/

Comment: “need to work with display:table” — I don’t understand what you mean by this. I can’t imagine a way to get `display:table` to work in IE 7 and 6 using JavaScript — given the way table layout works, I imagine it’d be really, really complicated, and unreliable. I’d suggest you keep your `display:table code`, but use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) to provide extra stylesheets for IE 7 & 6 that override your `display:table` code with the alternative CSS that works in IE.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to use tables for IE6 & IE7 using conditional comments:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]> special markup for IE6 and IE7 <![endif]-->
```

So, add table, tr, and td tags  properly, only for IE in your menu elements.

Another solution is to use: display:inline-block;