# word break in ie7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-tables

I need to allow word break/word wrap in the following structure :

```
<ul>
    <li><strong>Forename</strong><span>forename value</span></li>
    <li><strong>Forename</strong><span>forename value</span></li>
    <li><strong>Forename</strong><span>forename value</span></li>
<ul>
```

I can't fix a width to the span or li as the number of li's might vary. Making li to display as **table-cell** helps to word-break the span content like shown in the image.

[image]

- **Is there a way to make IE7 behave/understand table-cell ?**

**Edit :**

My original problem is I'm trying to achieve a display like shown in the image below, but just that the content is getting cut at the right if long unbroken strings are given as input, instead of breaking the word.

1. I'm wondering why **word-break:break-all** doesn't take effect unless when span is made block or inline-block ?
2. Even when span is made inline-block, the next problem is how to make the subsequent content flow on the continuos line ?

Attached image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gB92.png

Any thoughts please ?

Comment: Take a look here [ie7-and-the-css-table-cell-property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249103/ie7-and-the-css-table-cell-property). There is a good solution with jQuery by @andy magoon

Comment: This does not look like a word breaking question; rather, it’s about styling a list as a table. Any practical reason not to use a `table` element?

Answer (score 0):

You mean each of the three textblocks you have may not have more than 3 lines of text? If so:

```
<li style="height:100%;">
    <div style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden;">
         <strong>Forename</strong>
         <span>forename value</span>
    </div>
</li>
```

in this way  the fourth text line that may be there won't be visible.

I do not support IE7 anymore since it takes a lot of time to make a website compatible with it and the IE7 usage is around 5% i saw at some statistics.

I just pop a window if a visitor is using ie7 with the message that they use a browser which isn't updated anymore since the end of 2008, which makes them vulnerable. And advice them to update to a newer version. If we all do that, we get rid of IE7 quickly.

Comment: My initial problem itself is not to cut off the content or let it go hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my demo [in JSBin](http://jsbin.com/izaxen/2/edit)

You may check the `white-space` attribute of each `span` css to be sure that the value of `white-space` is `normal`, not `nowrap` - which prevent line-break;

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But that's not the display I'm looking for. Also table-cell doesn't work in IE7. Thanks anyway.